# Safety of passing an authorisation header to Angular 2 HttpInterceptor

Tags: angular

My Angular front end fetches data from my back end, using a REST API. The back end is protected by basic http authentication and it has an admin user and password. I am fetching the data through a service and decided to add an interceptor to add authorization to the requests as

```
@Injectable()
export class ApiInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const clone = req.clone({ setHeaders: { Authorization: `Basic ${RouteAuth.auth}` } })
        return next.handle(clone);
    }
}
```

Here `RouteAuth.auth` is fetched from a TS file. My issue is, this auth string is visible while inspecting the code through a browser debugger. How do I approach this?

Comment: When you put any code in angular as its a front end application, it will loaded to the browser. I dont think there is any was you can hide this. although you can encript them